# FOS Elastic Bundle Persisting error

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch

Hei, im just unsing the Fos Elastic Bundle, and when I'm tryng to persist two index I get no error but no data is created in the cloud.

I use `php app/console fos:elastica:populate` and I get this output:

```
Resetting app
 17/17 [============================] 100%
Populating app/professionalsRefreshing app
 10/10 [============================] 100%
Populating app/clinicsRefreshing app
Refreshing app
```

But when I try to acces to the cluster data (`/_search?=q=*&pretty`), I get no data

Anyone knows why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **Kibana** for viewing your data. 
The installation is really simple : 
https://www.elastic.co/en/products/kibana

Did you successfully insert data manually ?